# Loading Rails project's app paths in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing an application in Rails 5 and using Rspec for tests.  I'm having a lot of trouble with `require 'some_model'` or `require 'some_controller'` in my spec files.  Every time I run a spec, it acts lost and doesn't seem to understand that it's in a Rails app.  The suggestions I've seen range from

`config.autolad_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app )`

to

`$LOAD_PATH << '~/my_app/app/models'` which sort of works, except that my tests throw an unitialized constant for `ApplicationRecord`

So for all the digging around I've done, I still haven't found a good way `require` my MVC files while keeping my specs and `spec_helper` clean.  There doesn't seem to be any defacto way to do so, so how do you all suggest doing it?

Answer (score 1):

can you not take on the entire stress of RSpec configuration. Use the `rspec-rails` gem and [look through the documentation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) to use it within your app. I guess you can get a base config with `rails generate rspec:install` after including the gem in your project.